# How to Direct Menu Text to the Right and make the hover links go to the Left

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the [**couponia coupons online shop template**](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/couponia/demo_v3_3/index-coupon-layout-2.html) script that display simple page.

The menu link text are directed to **left** and when **Hover** above, it gives slightly move to the right. Like that:

[image]

I want the oppeset, i want the text links to be directed to the **right** and the links hover to go to **left**. Like that:

[image]

Here is the relevant **HTML** code:

```
       <div class="col-md-3">
            <aside class="sidebar-left">
                <h3 class="mb20">I am Looking For</h3>
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-coupon-category nav-coupon-category-left">
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>Food & Drink<span>40</span></a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Events</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Beauty</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>Fitness</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>Electronics</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-image"></i>Furniture</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-umbrella"></i>Fashion</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Shopping</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home & Graden</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i>Travel</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </aside>
        </div>
```

Here is the **CSS** Code:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 55px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #666;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a .fa {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a .fa:before {
  opacity: 0.65;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding-left: 65px;
  color: #2a8fbd;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover .fa {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover .fa:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover span {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a span {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a .fa {
  background: #298dba;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #2681aa;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a .fa:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:hover {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:hover span {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  top: 6px;
  right: -15px;
  background: #2a8fbd;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a [class^="fa fa-"] {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-right: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a:hover {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a [class^="fa fa-"] {
  border-left: 1px solid #2681aa;
  border-right: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: -15px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a:hover {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.15);
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li > a {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li > a:hover {
  padding-left: 55px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li.active > a:before {
  display: none;
}
```

See here the full css files:

[**Styles.css**](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/couponia/demo_v3_3/css/styles.css)

[**Bootstrap.css**](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/couponia/demo_v3_3/css/boostrap.css)

Live one you can see: **[Here](http://remtsoy.com/tf_templates/couponia/demo_v3_3/index-coupon-layout-2.html)**

It use Bootstarp and i tried to play with the CSS but without success. 
Any ideas how to preform that?

Comment: Starbuck I think I provided an answer that meets your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

try using

```
<div class="col-md-3" dir="rtl">
```

Comment: Not working. It takes the whole link text to the right and disable the slight move.

Answer (score 1):

You Just need to Change ul tag class from

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-coupon-category nav-coupon-category-left">
```

to

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-coupon-category nav-coupon-category-right">
```

This is example from your code provided:

```css
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 55px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #666;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a .fa {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a .fa:before {
  opacity: 0.65;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding-left: 65px;
  color: #2a8fbd;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover .fa {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover .fa:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover span {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a span {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a .fa {
  background: #298dba;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #2681aa;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a .fa:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:hover {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 55px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:hover span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  top: 6px;
  right: -15px;
  background: #2a8fbd;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a [class^="fa fa-"] {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-right: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a:hover {
  padding-left: 35px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a [class^="fa fa-"] {
  border-left: 1px solid #2681aa;
  border-right: none;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: -15px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a:hover {
  padding-left: 20px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li > a {
  border-bottom: none !important;
  padding-right: 15px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li > a:hover {
  padding-left: 55px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li.active > a:before {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3">
  <aside class="sidebar-right">
    <h3 class="mb20">I am Looking For</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-coupon-category nav-coupon-category-right">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>Food & Drink<span>40</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Events</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Beauty</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>Fitness</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>Electronics</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-image"></i>Furniture</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-umbrella"></i>Fashion</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Shopping</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home & Graden</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i>Travel</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: I tried that- it is not working. It only takes the icons to the right.

Comment: I cannot give you complete solution until I don't have your code, but I think it solved half of the problem

Comment: I added links to the full CSS files

Answer (score 0):

The `<div class="col-md-3" dir="rtl">` works, but it does not do the whole thing.

All you have to do is add this css. A transition addition would make the overall result look better.

```
li:hover {
    margin-right: 10px;
    transition: 0.5s;
}
```

To make your `div` stay on the left of the page, add this code. You can modify the pixels for your desire.

```
.col-md-3 {
    margin-right: 400px;
}
```

Also, `margin-left: 70px;` on `i` makes it closer to the outcome. You can set custom `margin-left` properties for each `i`.
Here is the complete snippet.

```css
i {
    margin-left: 70px;
}
.col-md-3 {
  margin-right: 400px;
}
.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category {
  margin-bottom: 30px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 3px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 13px;
  z-index: 1;
  -webkit-border-radius: 0;
  border-radius: 0;
  background: #fff;
  border-left: none;
  border-right: none;
  border: none;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
  height: 40px;
  line-height: 40px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 55px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0;
  color: #666;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a .fa {
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  font-size: 18px;
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #fbfbfb;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 40px;
  border-right: 1px solid #ededed;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a .fa:before {
  opacity: 0.65;
  -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=65)";
  filter: alpha(opacity=65);
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a span {
  margin-left: 10px;
  color: #bfbfbf;
  padding: 1px 7px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  font-size: 10px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
  -moz-transition: 0.2s;
  -o-transition: 0.2s;
  -ms-transition: 0.2s;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover {
  background: #fbfbfb;
  padding-left: 65px;
  color: #2a8fbd;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover .fa {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover .fa:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li > a:hover span {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li:first-child a {
  border-top: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > li:last-child a {
  border-bottom: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a {
  z-index: 2;
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a span {
  color: #fff;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a .fa {
  background: #298dba;
  color: #fff;
  border-right: 1px solid #2681aa;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a .fa:before {
  opacity: 1;
  -ms-filter: none;
  filter: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:hover {
  background: #2a8fbd;
  color: #fff;
  padding-left: 55px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:hover span {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category > .active > a:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  height: 28px;
  width: 28px;
  top: 6px;
  right: -15px;
  background: #2a8fbd;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  display: block;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right {
  margin-right: 0;
  margin-left: 30px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 20px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a [class^="fa fa-"] {
  left: auto;
  right: 0;
  border-left: 1px solid #ededed;
  border-right: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > li > a:hover {
  padding-left: 35px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a [class^="fa fa-"] {
  border-left: 1px solid #2681aa;
  border-right: none;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a:before {
  right: auto;
  left: -15px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-right > .active > a:hover {
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline {
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  margin: 0;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  box-shadow: 0 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  float: left;
  display: block;
  margin-right: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li > a {
  border-bottom: none !important;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-stacked.nav-coupon-category.nav-coupon-category-inline > li.active > a:before {
  display: none;
}
li:hover {
  margin-right: 10px;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3" dir="rtl">
  <aside class="sidebar-left">
    <h3 class="mb20">I am Looking For</h3>
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-stacked nav-coupon-category nav-coupon-category-left">
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-cutlery"></i>Food & Drink<span>40</span></a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>Events</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-female"></i>Beauty</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-bolt"></i>Fitness</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-headphones"></i>Electronics</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-image"></i>Furniture</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-umbrella"></i>Fashion</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Shopping</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i>Home & Graden</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-plane"></i>Travel</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </aside>
</div>
```

Comment: This is totally wrong, the icons are still on left side

Comment: This is pretty close to the answer.

Comment: nice that you still want to help him, but I think it will be useless untill he provide some good jsfiddle/code pen example of his code. Weldone for your efforts